# Facebook graph API: post to feed fails with "link" parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am posting a link to the feed of a page with Graph API. Last time I checked, my code was working a couple month ago. But today I find out that the same code stops working and returns an error.

Basically what I do is:

```
$ curl -i -F 'access_token=my_application_token' -F 'link=http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/tyler-florence/parsnip-puree-recipe2/index.html' -F 'name=Parsnip Puree' -F 'picture=http://img.foodnetwork.com/FOOD/2009/02/25/TU0603-1_Parsnip-Puree_s4x3_tz.jpg' -F 'id=my_page_url' https://graph.facebook.com/feed
```

It now returns the following result:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "unknown_error" "An unknown error has occurred."
X-FB-Rev: 600290
X-FB-Debug: mTeWwusHg5daIP2IMHlebi8fnLT9PO0CNJQeshMC+Hg=
Date: Mon, 30 Jul 2012 19:07:01 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 87

{"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}
```

If I try the same post without the parameter of "link", then it works:

```
$ curl -i -F 'access_token=my_application_token' -F 'name=Parsnip Puree' -F 'picture=http://img.foodnetwork.com/FOOD/2009/02/25/TU0603-1_Parsnip-Puree_s4x3_tz.jpg' -F 'id=my_page_url' https://graph.facebook.com/feed
```

This returns the following, and I can see the post on my Facebook wall (without the desired link, of course):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
X-FB-Rev: 600290
X-FB-Debug: iVVyk65AbEbnXNm0RyurLp/ZQA/oNXJ47w1UkLXXTfw=
Date: Mon, 30 Jul 2012 19:07:19 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 40

{"id":"155190691260287_268086653304xxx"}
```

What puzzles me is that the same code with "link" parameter had been working. And the Facebook documentation does not say anything has changed about the "link" parameter for posting to feed.

Any idea what went wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: same thing is happening to me too :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue lately, posting to page feeds with links seems to fail by the reply, however the post is still created. I have the proper permissions and the app is public.  There's currently a bug-report opened at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/726825557390253 that might shed some light on the problem should a FB dev respond!